Software for managing product drops in a private club
I help run a club that brings in products, which are then released. Ideally, I need software to manage the user base with contact info (++ if able to send emails or SMS), collect reservations (including the ability to use "auto-ins" stored in the user database), randomize if the demand exceeds the availability, and then send scannable tickets to those who were selected.
I know this is a reach! We have funds to work with. I am also happy to stitch things together with APIs if needed. Hoping not to code something from scratch. We are currently using Google Forms and manually looking at auto-ins, then using paper reservation tables for the pickups. I have thought about automating some of the Forms fields (auto-ins and contact info), but am hoping a better solution exists.
